# How to select not-direct left sibling <span> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
<span>This is the span I want to select</span>
<div>something here</div>
<a id="start"></a>
```

Suppose can only access $('#start'),

I tried $('#start').prev('span') but not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#start')
    .parent()       // gets one up
    .find('span')   // gets the span element
```

[same code](http://jsbin.com/aniza/edit) using [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) sandbox

---

**Note:**

you can't use prev() as it only gets the previous tag, and span, from the anchor tag is not the previous is the previous of the previous

from [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev)

> Get a set of elements containing the unique previous siblings of each of the matched set of elements.
>   Use an optional expression to filter the matched set. **Only the immediately previous sibling is returned**, not all previous siblings.

```
prev([filter])
```

the filter is to filter if the previous tag contains more than one, like:

```
<div>
   <span></span>
   <a></a>
</div>
<a id="a2"></a>
```

to get the span you use:

```
$('#a2').prev('span')
```

Comment: added to the answer why you can't use it :)

Comment: Check my answer, you'll get the very first span behind your element, so long as it's a sibling.

Comment: for the html he exposed, I presented my solution :)

Comment: Mine works with his HTML. I just added an extra span to show that it actually got the one he wanted. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, it seems that `prevAll` goes backwards, starting at the first one right behind the starting element and working its way back. Makes sense, I suppose. Either way, the following worked for me:

```
//jquery :

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").prevAll("span:first").css("font-weight", "bold");
  });

// html: 


<span>This is the span I don't want to select</span>
<span>This is the span I want to select</span>
<div>something here</div>
<a id="start">Stuff</a>
```